# alternative to JQuery .slideDown()

Tags: jquery

Is there an alternative to jquery slideDown() that is known of?

The reason I ask is that I think slideDown should really be named roll down as it kind of unravels contents as opposed to them actually sliding down.

This is an example of the effect I mean - mouseover one of the main items on the page (doesn't work in ie): [Example slide down](http://foodgawker.com/)

Ideally needs to work in IE too so I'm guessing this is more transition than js which is ok when everyone on ie10, might take a while!

Comment: I can't get your question. Are you complaining only about the name, i.e. semantics, of the function?

Comment: You can create your own variant with the handy `.animate()` method.

Comment: Seems like you're just trying to something like this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/U7AxG/) ?

Comment: It really looks like the site you linked is animating the top/bottom position rather than the height of the elements.

Comment: @adeneo Please `stop` it first: http://jsfiddle.net/U7AxG/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would do this is set my container to position relative and an overflow hidden;
Then have my hover over as position absolute with a top of -50px, then use jquery animate to move it down on hover.

[An example is here](http://jsfiddle.net/domjgreen/wenYD/)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="hover"></div>   
</div>

.container{width:400px;height:400px; border:1px solid grey; position:relative;overflow:hidden;}
.hover{position:absolute;top:-50px; width:100%;height:50px; background-color:red;}

$('.container').hover(function() {
    $('.hover').animate({
        top: '+=50'
    });
},function(){
    $('.hover').animate({
        top: '-=50'
    });

});
```

Answer (score 3):

With a bit more of code you can use `.animate()`.

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

a small example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(element).toggle(function(){
    $(this).animate({height:40},200);
  },function(){
    $(this).animate({height:10},200);
  });
});
```